# CentOS 6 IPTABLES list rules

Tags: centos, iptables, centos-6

I've entered some rules into IPtables on CentOS 6. But when I run 'service iptables status' I get a different result than when I go 'iptables -L'.

I need to open up port 1270 on this machine.

This is what I see when I go 'service iptables status'

```
[root@server01 sysconfig]# service iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 000 reject all icmp requests */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 002 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 22 /* 100 allow ssh access */
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 443,8443 /* 110 allow https access */
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1556
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:13782
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:13724
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.48.131.220        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1556
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.48.131.220        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:13782
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.48.131.220        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:13724
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5222
15   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5269
16   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.36.16.25          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1270
17   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.36.16.26          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1270
18   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.36.16.37          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1270
19   ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.36.16.31          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1270

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

And this is what I see when I go iptables -L

```
[root@server01 sysconfig]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 000 reject all icmp requests */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 002 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports ssh /* 100 allow ssh access */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports https,pcsync-https /* 110 allow https access */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          anywhere            tcp dpt:veritas_pbx
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          anywhere            tcp dpt:bpcd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.1.190.65          anywhere            tcp dpt:vnetd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  uawscdap0000.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:veritas_pbx
ACCEPT     tcp  --  uawscdap0000.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:bpcd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  uawscdap0000.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:vnetd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:xmpp-client
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:xmpp-server
ACCEPT     tcp  --  abckpap6181.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:opsmgr
ACCEPT     tcp  --  abckpap6182.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:opsmgr
ACCEPT     tcp  --  abcepap6782.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:opsmgr
ACCEPT     tcp  --  abcepap6783.us.companyworld.company.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:opsmgr

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

So, is port 120 open on this machine or not? Why am I see a difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't spot any difference, perhaps you are talking about the name resolution of IPs and port numbers?
If so, you need the `-n` option for "numeric" output.

`iptables -L -n`

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes that's exactly what I mean. I didn't understand that iptables was resolving the DNS name of the ip addresses in the output of iptables -L. Why does it do that? Thanks

Comment: Many network tools do that by default to be more human friendly. Thankfully, they commonly also support an option to turn it off as well, and it's usually -n.